# SQL Server Parent/Child Trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have two entities in a database that behave in a parent/child relationship.

- A record in the parent table contains a total quantity
- A record(s) in the child table must sum to less-than/equal-to the parent total

I have two triggers

- The parent table trigger checks that changes do not violate the constraint based on the child values
- The child table trigger checks that changes do not violate the constraint based on the parent values

The business application allows the user to update the two simultaneously. For example I can add a parent total, and add child line items in the same form submission. Or I can increase/decrease both sides of existing quantities in the same transaction.

The problem occurs when the user wants to zero-out a parent and zero-out all its children. The transaction starts by attempting to zero out the parent, which triggers a violation, and rollback the transaction.

So you may say just invert the order. But if I try to insert children without inserting the parent first, then I will also violate the other trigger in situations where the user is creating new records.

What I'm looking for is if there is something equivalent to a deferred trigger (which I don't think there is). I could also remove the triggers altogether, enforce the rules within the SP, but is that the best option here? I'm hesitant to leave the tables open like that without checks on the data.

**Edit- Added Trigger Sample**

The column names aren't exact but the logic is identical to what I'm using.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_child ON tbl_child
AFTER UPDATE,INSERT AS

BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT PARENT_ID,ParentQty FROM (SELECT PARENT_ID, SUM(QTY) AS ChildQty FROM INSERTED GROUP BY PARENT_ID) 
        JOIN tbl_parent WHERE ChildQTY>ParentQty)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Child quantities exceed parent',16,1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END 
ELSE
END
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code for your triggers

Comment: ANd you should probaly havea a seaprte insert trigger and a separate update trigger and a spearte delte trigger if need be. This is one where you would not want to try to do everything in one trigger.

Comment: I added the sample for you, though I'm not sure it's very helpful. Also the logic for an INSERT/UPDATE is identical thus the same trigger

Comment: Could you make every transaction zero all children, adjust the parent, and then assign the children quantities? That's the only safe order I can think of that won't violate the triggers.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have two stored procedures? One to update the master. One to update the line items. On the business application side, it would encapsulate both into a single transaction but alter the order of the sequence depending on operation?

Answer (score 0):

`I could also remove the triggers altogether, enforce the rules within the SP, but is that the best option here? I'm hesitant to leave the tables open like that without checks on the data.`

This is an age-old dilemma with tables like OrderHeader and OrderDetail. Purists will say that to store the line-item total in the parent is a denormalization and tell you that you've made your bed so sleep in it.  I would recommend taking away all direct update/insert/delete permissions on the tables, handling all write-related I/O through stored procedures which wrap operations in a transaction and do a sanity-check before commit.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, the header data isn't denormalization because its the amount of product allocated to a sales rep. He/she may use only a partial quantity leaving a balance. Though as you write that, I'm wondering if I can remove the QTY from the parent and add a QTY as a child which represents the balance. That might solve my issue then?

Comment: Triggers are not going to handle the complexities of allocating items from inventory to sales reps, some or all of which may need to be returned back into inventory. You will need a row representing an allocation of a quantity to a sales rep, and rows representing the consumption of the allocation by the sales rep. The rule you need to enforce is "Consumed quantity can never exceed total allocated quantity".  A trigger can do that. But if you're going to "undo" an allocation, you have the consumption history rows to worry about.

Comment: To handle the "undo-ing" of an allocation (i.e.  reversal or reduction) you can use an AllocationAdjustments table for adjusting entries. Your trigger on AllocationConsumption (i.e. sales reps use of items allocated to them) can calculate the total available allocation by looking at Allocation and AllocationAdjustments, and refuse to let the sales rep consume a quantity greater than is currently available. And your trigger on AllocationAdjustments can look at Allocation and AllocationConsumption to make sure that a quantity greater than or equal to the desired decrement remains unconsumed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make this comment an answer since I believe it addresses the problem posed, and it uses triggers:

`The problem occurs when the user wants to zero-out a parent and zero-out all its children...`

Ignoring the parent/child ERD for a moment, the only problemmatic word in this requirement is "all".  You can "zero-out" only the *unconsumed* quantity, which might not be all, since you're dealing with items in the real world. You allocate widgets to sales reps. The sales reps sell 50% of them and ship them to customers. You cannot deallocate 100% since only half of the widgets remain.

To handle the "undo-ing" of an allocation (i.e. reversal or reduction) you can use an **AllocationAdjustments** table for adjusting entries. Your trigger on **AllocationConsumption** (i.e. sales reps use of items allocated to them) can calculate the total available allocation by looking at **Allocation** and **AllocationAdjustments**, and refuse to let the sales rep consume a quantity greater than is currently available. And your trigger on **AllocationAdjustments** can look at **Allocation** and **AllocationConsumption** to make sure that a quantity greater than or equal to the desired decrement remains unconsumed.

Comment: Are you keeping records stored in AllocationAdjustments? Or is that temporary to overcome the trigger violations? I mean I could avoid this issue by calling two separate transactions. One to set the master allocation. One to set the individual consumption. Then run them in the appropriate order if using insert/update or total removal. The issue then is not being able to rollback on a transaction failure.

Comment: Also to clarify, the system strictly tracks allocation. It does not capture sales. So when a rep is allocated product, his/her "consumption" is the act of allocating it to one of the rep's accounts. Partial adjustments are fine and tracked in a history table. But your idea makes sense as I read it, and I will look at it tomorrow